# SQL syntax when hosting on 000webhost

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run a MySQL query in PHP code on my local host. It is running perfectly when I host the database and PHP page. The phpMyAdmin database of 000webhost is continuously calling my query with the wrong SQL syntax. I have rechecked the column names but they all are same.

Below is my query and the given error by 000webhost database:

```
select * from taxi
    where 'registration_number' NOT IN (
        select 'taxi_registration_number' from shift
        where 'shift_date' = 'sysdate'
    );
```

error given is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: No @halfer. this is just something i copied here.  Even If I  delete "  still error remains same.

Comment: Not possible. The host you're connected to doesn't alter the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use single quotes around column identifiers. Either use ticks or nothing at all.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    taxi
WHERE
    `registration_number` NOT IN (SELECT 
            `taxi_registration_number`
        FROM
            shift
        WHERE
            `shift_date` = 'sysdate');
```

Comment: ^ Closing bracket, @Worried_user? What error are you getting now?

Comment: select * from taxi where registration_number NOT IN (select taxi_registration_number from shift where shift_date = 'sysdate')

 this ^ is the exact sql query which is repeateldt pruducing error saying  syntax error. When i am running it over hosted database in 000webhost

Comment: @halfer my bad. I even corrected this -> ) still error remains. I am really surpirse over. can you help :(

Comment: @Worried_user: I can't see anything further wrong with your query, now you have corrected your comment. You might have to set up a [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) for us to look at. My guess is the query and/or the structure in your remote server is different to the query/structure locally (where, I presume, it works).

Comment: plus, one more thing @ halfer. If I need to setup reminders/alerts at my database. so that it can give alerts  on/just before expiry date of MOT etc. What procedure should I use. i am new to database. plus I guess I have to use cron jobs or something like. (I heard) Can you help. by proving any useful link or something

Comment: @Worried_user, yes a Cron will do fine here. If you hold an MOT expiry date, you can do a SQL query to see if any notifications are due by comparing to the current date. The cron can run once a day. (Aside: if you put a space after the 'at' symbol, comment notification does not work - I am only seeing your reply by accident).

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes:

```
select * from taxi where registration_number NOT IN (
   select taxi_registration_number from shift where shift_date = 'sysdate'
);
```